# Lebesgue and Jordan measure and some example

Tags: measure-theory

Let $S$ be semiring with identity element $E$ and $m$ is $\sigma$-additive measure on $S$.

> **Theorem:** Suppose $S$ - semiring. Then minimal ring, containing $S$ is the following set: $$R(S)=\left\{\bigsqcup
>  \limits_{i=1}^{n}A_i:A_i\in S\right\}.$$ In other words, $R(S)$ is the
>   family of all finite disjoint unions of sets in $S$.
>
> **Definition 1:** If $A\subset E$, then we define *outer Jordan measure* in the following way: $$\mu_J^*(A)=\inf \left\{\sum
>  \limits_{i=1}^{n}m(A_i): A_1,\dots, A_n\in S, A\subseteq
>  \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n}A_i\right\}.$$
>
> **Definition 2:** If $A\subset E$, then we define *outer Lebesgue measure* in the following way: $$\mu^*(A)=\inf \left\{\sum
>  \limits_{i=1}^{\infty}m(A_i): A_1, A_2,\dots\in S, A\subseteq
>  \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\right\}.$$
>
> **Remark 1:** It is not so difficult to show that for any $A\subseteq E$ we have $\mu^*(A)\leq \mu^*_J(A)$.
>
> **Remark 2:** *("Triangle inequality" for measure)* If $A, B\subseteq E$ then the following estimate holds: $$|\mu^*(A)-\mu^*(B)|\leq
>  \mu^*(A\triangle B)$$
>
> Also the same "triangle inequality" is true for outer Jordan measure.
>
> **Definition:** We say that $A\subseteq E$ is *Lebesgue measurable* (*Jordan measurable*), if for any $\varepsilon>0$ $\exists
>  A_{\varepsilon}\in R(S)$ such that $\mu^*(A\triangle
>  A_{\varepsilon})<\varepsilon$ ($\mu_J^*(A\triangle
>  A_{\varepsilon})<\varepsilon$). Denote by $M$ and $M_J$ the family of
>   all subsets of $E$ which are Lebesgue measurable and Jordan
>   measurable, respectively.

Then by remark 1 it follows that $M_J\subseteq M$. Also, note that $R(S)\subseteq M_J\subseteq M$. But the below example will show that $M_J\neq M$.

**Example:** Denote by $\{a,b\}$ the following intervals: $[a,b], [a,b), (a,b], (a,b)$. Consider the semiring $S=\{\{a,b\}:\{a,b\}\subseteq [0,1]\}$ with identity $E=[0,1]$. Consider the set $E=\mathbb{Q}_{[0,1]}\subset [0,1]$.

Then we  can show that $\mu^*(E)=0$ and $\mu^*_J(E)=1$. I can show that $E\in M$.

But how to show that $E\notin M_J$?

I have tried to prove by contradiction and also tries to use remark $2$ but no results. I would be very thankful if anyojne can show the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Similiarly to how you showed that $\mu_J^*(E) = 1$, you should be able to show that every dense subset of $[0,1]$ has outer Jordan measure 1.  Now show that for any set $B \in R(S)$, the set $E \triangle B$ is dense.  Hence you cannot find any $B \in R(S)$ for which $\mu_J^*(E \triangle B)$ is small.

To show $E \triangle B$ is dense, let $(a,b) \subset [0,1]$ be an arbitrary interval. We have to show that $(a,b)$ contains a point of $E \triangle B$. If $(a,b)$ contains a point of $E \setminus B$ we are done.  If not, then $B$ contains all the rationals in $(a,b)$.  But since $B$ has to look like a finite union of intervals, show that in this case, $B$ contains some irrationals from $(a,b)$ (you fill in the details), so that $(a,b)$ contains a point of $B \setminus E$.

Comment: I have realized that my proof of $\mu^*_J(E)=1$ was wrong. I have found the following link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1226220/jordan-outer-content-of-rationals-in-0-1 but I cannot understand why they consider intervals of type $[a,b)$. Because in the definition of outer Jordan measure we can any type of intervals. Could you explain it, please?

Comment: They are probably working with a different definition of Jordan outer measure.  Different books define it in different ways.  All definitions should turn out to be equivalent but this would have to be proved.

Comment: I do not have time to write it out.  But the idea will be that you are trying to cover $E$ by a *finite* number of intervals.  You can assume without loss of generality that they are all closed intervals, as this does not change their measure.  You can also merge any two intervals that overlap, and assume that the intervals are disjoint (this will only decrease the  measure).  If there is any gap between them, that is an open interval which contains a rational, and so $E$ is not covered.  If there is no gap, then the total measure is at least 1.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Q= \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$. Suppose $I \subset [0,1]$ is an interval, then
$\mu_J^* (Q \cap I) = \mu_J^* I$. Similarly, $\mu_J^*(I \setminus Q)= \mu_J^* I$.

If $I_k \in S$ are pairwise disjoint, then
$\mu_J^* (A \cap (I_1 \cup \cdots \cup I_l)) = \mu_J^* (A \cap I_1) + \cdots + \mu_J^* ( A \cap I_l)$ (for any $A \subset [0,1]$).

Note that $[0,1] \in S$ so for any $B \in S$ we have $B^c \in S$.

Suppose $Q \subset A_1\cup\cdots \cup A_n$ where $A_i \in S$. Without loss of generality, we can assume the $A_i$ are pairwise disjoint. We can also write
$(A_1\cup\cdots \cup A_n)^c = B_1\cup\cdots \cup B_m$, where the $B_j \in S$ are
pairwise disjoint.

Hence $Q \triangle (A_1\cup\cdots \cup A_n) = (Q \cap B_1) \cup \cdots \cup (Q \cap B_m) \cup (A_1 \setminus Q) \cup \cdots \cup (A_n \setminus Q)$, and so
$\mu_J^* (Q \triangle (A_1\cup\cdots \cup A_n)) = \mu_J^* B_1 + \cdots + \mu_J^* B_m + \mu_J^* A_1 + \cdots + \mu_J^* A_n = 1$.

The reason this works for $\mu^*$ is because we can find a countable collection of $A_i \in S$  such that $Q \subset \cup_i A_i$ and $\cup_i A_i$ has
arbitrarily small $\mu^*$ measure. Hence $Q \triangle \cup_i A_i = \cup_i (A_i \setminus Q) \subset \cup_i A_i$.

**Addendum**:
To see why $\mu_J^* (Q \cap I) = \mu_J^* I$: Note that $\mu_J^* (Q \cap I) \le \mu_J^* I$ follows by definition. Suppose $Q \cap I \subset A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n$. with $A_i \in S$. Then $I \setminus (A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n)$ must be finite and only the endpoints of the intervals can be missing). Then we can replace
the $A_i$ by $\overline{A_i}$ which have the same $m$ measure and $I \subset 
\overline{A_1} \cup \cdots \cup \overline{A_n}$. Hence, taking $\inf$s we
have $\mu_J^* (Q \cap I) = \mu_J^* I$.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I many moments of your reply is not so clear. Firstly, why $\mu_J^*(Q\cap I)=\mu_J^*(I)$?

Comment: Also notice that my definition of semiring does not require closedness under complement. But I guess that your definition does require!

Comment: @ZFR: I thought you were looking at the set $[0,1]$ and since $[0,1] \in S$ then for any element $ A \in S$ we have that $[0,1] \setminus A \in S$.

Comment: But this is true if definition of semiring has complement property, right?

Comment: @ZFR: I suspect that this is tangential to the proof, but in general, a semiring need not contain the entire space.

Comment: For example, the semiring consisting of finite intervals of the form $[a,b)$ does not contain $\mathbb{R}$.